# System.TypeInitializationException:

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I would like to ask for help because I got stuck in exploring the problem.
I'm a beginner developer if I made a big mistake of understanding and asking for your help :)

I started writing a program where I created a static class for sql queries and connection. After logging in, the dgv should display the data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ParkingMaster
{
    static class SqlHandle
    {
        static SqlConnection connection;
        static SqlCommand command;

       static SqlHandle ()
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ParkingMaster.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ToString();

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection opened!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }  
        }

        public static void ConnClose()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "Hiba a kapcsolat bezárásakor");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static List<Cars> ReadList()
        {
            List<Cars> results = new List<Cars>();

            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Cars]";
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(new Cars(
                        (int)reader["car_id"],
                        reader["car_plate_id_char"].ToString(),
                       (int)reader["car_plate_id_num"],
                       (DateTime)reader["creationdate"]));
                }
                reader.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParkingMaster
{
    class Cars
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Plate_id_char { get; set; }
        public int Plate_id_num { get; set; }
        public DateTime Creationdate { get; set; }

        /*    
        public string FullInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{id} {plate_id_char} {plate_id_num} {creationdate}";
            }
        }
        */

        public Cars(int id, string plate_id_char, int plate_id_num, DateTime creationdate)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Plate_id_char = plate_id_char;
            this.Plate_id_num = plate_id_num;
            this.Creationdate = creationdate;
        }



    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;


namespace ParkingMaster
{
    public partial class mainForm : Form
    {
        List<Cars> cars;
        List<Cars> keresett_cars;
        //DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection();


        public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //carFoundListbox.DataSource = cars;
        }

        private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cars = SqlHandle.ReadList();
                datagridview_megjelenit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Hiba", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void btnVehicleListDgv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void datagridview_megjelenit()
        {
            //Inicializálás
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo elem in typeof(Cars).GetProperties())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(elem.Name, elem.Name);
                }
            }
            foreach (Cars item in cars) //sorok
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); //sorokon belül az oszlopok (mezők) hozzáadása
                for (int i = 0; i < typeof(Cars).GetProperties().Length; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[i].Value = typeof(Cars).GetProperties()[i].GetValue(item);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: TypeInitializationException *usually* (if not always) occurs due to an error in the static constructor. So you have to understand what is the real exception that occurred (you can either debug it or add logging)

Comment: IMHO you should *not* be trying to open a connection the way you are. You should be creating static calls that create, open and close the connections and that goes for the command class as well.

Comment: Although I've given a simple answer below, I agree with @Çöđěxěŕ regarding your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception occurs when there is an unhandled exception in a static constructor.

In your case, I am guessing, you are trying to access the `ConnectionString` property of the `SQLConnection connection` before you have instantiated `connection`.

Instead of

```
connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ParkingMaster.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ToString();
```

try

```
SQLConnection connection = new SQLConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ParkingMaster.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! Managed in this form:

```
 static SqlHandle ()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ParkingMaster.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ToString());

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection opened!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }  
    }
```